# What diagram use to show client needs (at CRM)

Tags: uml, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, diagram, crm

What do you usually use to show client structure, data, etc.? Which diagram UML? Or you use something else?

I must show/prepare to my client diagram about solution to his CRM process. I looking for best diagram UML for that.

Waiting for answers.

Thanks.

Comment: I downvoted your question and flagged it as "Not a real question" because I can't understand from what you've asked what you're really asking. If you can edit your question to be more clear/specific about what you're asking, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I found the question easy enough to understand. As far as deciding whether or not to use UML, I would suggest the author consider the audience. Regardless of the type of diagram, I prefer Microsoft Visio, however there are a number of other fine tools available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CRM 2011, it's all about the entities.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2640

Answer (score 1):

How about a CRM 2011 Visio add-in? Explanation here: 
http://everythingcrm.net/2012/02/09/crm-2011-visio-add-in-org-chart-for-business-units/

Can be downloaded here: http://crmvisio.codeplex.com/

Kudos to: Darko Jovisic

Answer (score 0):

There is a [company](http://www.magnetism.co.nz/blog/11-01-11/CRM_2011_Visio_Stencil_Set_The_Final_Product.aspx) that sales a CRM 2011 Visio Stencil Set which can be useful there is a older free one [CRM 4.0 Visio Stencil](http://weblogs.asp.net/gayanperera/archive/2008/12/10/dynamics-crm-4-visio-stencils.aspx), it's based on CRM 4.0 but it will still be helpful.

Comment: This is nice Visio template, but I looking for something like UML diagram. Or which UML diagram will be best to show CRM structure to client?